# Нарисовать линию между двумя точками, имея только координаты этих точек.

Tags: c, алгоритм

Без специальных функций, которые специально для этого предназначены. 
Например, вот

```
struct map
{
  int x[100];
  int y[100];
} Map;
...
//Позиция точки 1
Map.x[0]=0;
Map.y[0]=0;
//Позиция точки 2
Map.x[1]=10;
Map.y[1]=15;
```

Имея только координаты точки необходимо каким-либо образом определить те элементы массивов, через которые проходит линия. 
Вот, даже картинка:

http://2.firepic.org/2/images/2013-12/18/x9vwzlg8tmeq.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Алгоритм Брезенхэма](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%B0) же!